# I need some help solving a SQL query, I need to list the names of consumers requesting at least one product but not requesting milk

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqliteopenhelper

I need help solving the query "List names of customers that are requesting at least one product but not requesting milk. I have a rough start on it, but I have no idea how to finish it. Here's what I have so far.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Tb_Consumer.Con_ID, Tb_Consumer.Name
FROM 
    Tb_Consumer, Tb_Requests
WHERE 
    Tb_Consumer.Con_ID = Tb_Requests.Con_ID  
    AND Tb_Consumer.Con_ID NOT IN (SELECT Tb_Consumer.Con_ID)
```

The output I'm looking for is this.

```
Con_id    Name
----------------
  2       Hammer
  4       Hoffer
```

Comment: Tb_Requests tables column name please

Comment: Why did you tag both SQLServer and sqlite?

Comment: The problem statement is ambiguous. Does "but no requesting milk" mean one product other than milk, or that any request for milk disqualifies the consumer from the query completely?

Comment: Also: `TableA, TableB` joins, as with  `Tb_Consumer, Tb_Requests`, have been obsolete for more than 25 years now. **Don't use them!** Write out `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` and put the join conditions in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: And what does this even do `Not in (SELECT Tb_Consumer.Con_ID)`?

Comment: Without sample input, how are we supposed to magically generate the output you want?

Comment: I just noticed, why have you tagged `sqliteopenhelper`? That has nothing to do with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

use not exists i assume you have a `product_name` column in table `Tb_Requests`

```
    select distinct c.* from Tb_Consumer c join Tb_Requests t1 on c.Con_ID=t1.Con_ID
    where not exists( select 1 from Tb_Requests t where c.Con_ID=t.Con_ID
                      and product_name='milk')
```

Comment: No need for the `JOIN` to `Tb_Requests` here., as you're not returning any data in the `SELECT`. The `EXISTS` is enough.

Comment: but there is a condition at least one product request you have done which will confirm request table join

Comment: Yes, you're right. If they have multiple requests, then you would get duplicates though.

Comment: Did make me realise mine is probably wrong. :) *(Now fixed too)*

Comment: @GameGandhi555 OK, but we can't see your screen. :)

Comment: I can see I didn't post anything lol, I get this error code Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'milk' to data type int

Comment: We don't know the name of your columns @GameGandhi555, we can't see your data, so Zayah has guessed. Use the column with the name of your product in the table `Tb_Requests`. Otherwise, replace the literal string `'Milk'` with the ID of the product `'Milk'`. I don't mean to offend, but you should try to solve simple problems like that one yourself or you'll never learn.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `EXISTS` you could use `HAVING`. This'll save on 2 scans/seeks of the table `tb_Requests`.

```
SELECT C.Con_ID, C.[Name]
FROM Tb_Consumer C
     JOIN Tb_Requests R ON C.Con_ID = R.Con_ID
GROUP BY C.Con_ID, C.[Name]
HAVING COUNT(R.Req_ID) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE R.Product_name WHEN 'Milk' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```